# Background não se repete ao diminuir tamanho da janela

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia
Tenho o seguinte site: http://goo.gl/On8Wtx
O que acontece é que os backgrounds não estao se repetindo ao diminuir a janela do navegador. Já tentei de tudo quanto é jeito e não funciona, já tirei a responsividade do bootstrap e mesmo assim não adiantou.
Alguém sabe me dizer o porque acontece isso? Lmebrando que esse template eu já peguei pronto e fui estilizando

Obrigado

Comment: Não entendi o que precisa, precisa que o background seja o mesmo em toda a pagina ?

Comment: Parece bobagem, mas sera que não é porque o seu arquivo CSS não esta sendo encontrado?    http://www.aobrigadeiro.com.br/font/zocial.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Eu ja tirei esses arquivos que nao estao sndo carregados e continua a mesma coisa

Comment: Lembrando que estou testando localhost, mas online ele também da esse problema ai quando redimensiono a janela

Comment: Não deu pra entender se você quer que o background fique em todas as páginas ou se é para criar um mosaico com o mesmo background em um tela.